# Jsdom not returning document

Tags: javascript, html, jsdom

I am trying to use jsdom to load a local HTML file, this is the code

```
var config = {
      file: "filename",
      scripts: ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
      done: function(err, window){
          console.log(window.document.URL)
          console.log(window.document.children)
      }
}
jsdom.env(config)
```

`window.document.URL` displays the correct url, but `window.document.innerHTML` doesnt have any data. Ive even tried

```
var config = {
      text: *raw-html*,
      scripts: ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
      done: function(err, window){
          console.log(window.document.children)
      }
}
```

but I had the same results, any help?

### Update

I have found that

```
var rawhtml = fs.readFileSync("filename.html","utf8")
jsdom.env(
  rawhtml,
  ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  function (err, window) {
    console.log(window.$("html").html())
  }
);
```

works as expected (it logs everything inside the `html` tags)

I then found that

```
config = {
  file: "filename.html",
  scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  done: function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    console.log($("html").html());
  }
} 
jsdom.env(config);
```

also works, but again neither will create the `document` object correctly

## "Solution"

jsdom does not show the output of `document.children` in the same way a browser console would, however, all of the functionality you would expect is there. The final working `document` object  is below

```
var func = function(document){
  console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
  document.body.innerHTML = "i changed the body"


}
function getdoc(file, func){
  var document;
  jsdom.env(
    file,
    (err, window) => {
      document = window.document
      func(document)
      }
  );
}
getdoc("index.html",code)
```

I use `jsdom.env()` to get the `document`, then pass the `document` to `func` where all the fun javascript magic is free to happen. Keep in mind that any changes made to the `document` need to be manually saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `document.innerHTML` property.

Check `"innerHTML" in document`; -you'll get `false`.

Comment: Try document.documentElement, document.all[0], in chrome you can also do document.children[0] for html element innerHTML

Comment: You are right, I meant to put document.children Ill edit the post to reflect that. document.children doesn't return any elements.

Comment: you should use a cross browser method, only chrome does return children on document keyword, and I don't know why it does that.